# Custom UITableViewCell does not size properly when Accessory is added

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm having trouble getting a custom UITableViewCell to size properly when an Accessory is set. Why does the Accessory blow the cell sizing up on the initial display? When I scroll, with the accessory set, the sizing corrects itself - however, the initial view is not sizing correctly.

I've watched the WWDC14 (what's new in tableview) video several times and I've read many stackoverflow questions and tried many solutions. I think I have most of the problem solved - cells do resize for dynamic text - but I'm stumped on this strange initial behavior. I am running XCode 6.1.1 deploying to iOS 8.1.

I'm using a storyboard. I have a UITableViewController and custom UITableViewCell. I define constraints in the storyboard and there are no constraint warnings and I see no constraint messages in the console at runtime.

In my UITableViewController viewDidLoad()

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

with override

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

    cell.configure(titles[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

This is my entire custom UITableViewCell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

func configure(title: NSString) {
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = frame.width
}
```

}

This is what it looks like when Accessory None is set on the cell

[image]

This is what it looks like when I set Accessory Disclosure Indicator on the cell

[image]

Again, when I scroll with the accessory set the sizing corrects itself. I've tried adding a vertical constraint to the cell both in storyboard and also by adding all constraints programmatically with no success. Thank you for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem too with storyboard designed self-sizing cells. Try adding `self.layoutIfNeeded()` to an override of `didMoveToSuperview` in your cell class. I don't know if this is a bug, or we're just missing something that we're supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar, unfortunately this didn't work for me and some side-effect broke wrapping. I may have a problem with my Xcode installation/simulators - a colleague and I both ran a tutorial project and my instance didn't populate any data in a table and his did. I'm seeing very erratic behavior. I'm investigating that and will update with an answer if I can.